# How do I get my Generate() method to recognize the values I set in my Password() method?

Tags: java

I have this block:

```
public Password2 (int numofSymbols, int numofCap, int numofLow, int numofDigit )throws Exception{
        if(numofSymbols<2||numofCap<2||numofLow<2||numofDigit<2){
        throw new Exception("Settings supplied not accpeted");
    }
    this.numofSymbols=numofSymbols;
    this.numofCap=numofCap;
    this.numofLow=numofLow;
    this.numofDigit=numofDigit; 
    System.out.println("New Settings:"+"\n"+"Symbols: "+numofSymbols+"\n"+"Capitals: "+numofCap+"\n"+"Lowercase: "+numofLow+"\n"+"Digits: "+numofDigit); 
    }
```

and later I call it with:

```
  try{
    Password2 p1= new Password2();
    System.out.print("Default Password:");
    System.out.println(p1.getPassword());
    p1.setPassword();
    System.out.println(p1.getPassword());
  }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

and it works fine but the variables are not saved when I use this method:

```
public ArrayList<String> Generate(){
        ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
        Random rand=new Random();
    int count=0;
    while(count<5) {
        String placeholder="";
        int a;
                  
            
        for(int i=0;i<=numofCap;i++){
            a='Z'+1-'A';
            a=rand.nextInt(a)+'A';
            placeholder+=(char)a;
        }
                    
    
            for(int i=0;i<=numofLow;i++){
            a='z'+1-'a';
            a=rand.nextInt(a)+'a';
            placeholder+=(char)a;
        }
                 
       
        for(int i=0;i<=numofDigit;i++){
            a='9'+1-'0';
            a=rand.nextInt(a)+'0';
            placeholder+=(char)a;
        }
                    
        for(int i=0;i<=numofSymbols;i++){
            a=48+1-32;
            a=rand.nextInt(a)+32;
            placeholder+=(char)a;
        }        
         

        
        if(Consecutive(placeholder)==true){
            continue;
        }
        count++;
        result.add(placeholder);
    }
 // return the ArrayList
        //System.out.println(result); 
        return result;
    }
```

Ive tried a few solutions but im just lost. Here is all of my code it is for a project and it is very confusing:

```
import java.util.*;
class Password1{
protected static String defaultPassword = "nDay@159";
protected static int length = 8;
protected static int numofSymbols;
protected static int numofCap;
protected static int numofLow;
protected static int numofDigit;
Password1(){
    numofSymbols = 1;
    numofCap = 1;
    numofLow = 1;
    numofDigit = 1;
}
void Password1( int numofSymbols, int numofCap, int numofLow, int numofDigit ){
    Password1.numofSymbols = numofSymbols;
    Password1.numofCap = numofCap;
    Password1.numofLow = numofLow;
    Password1.numofDigit = numofDigit;
    
}
public boolean validLength(String pass){
    if(pass.length() >= length){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean validSymbols(String pass){
    int count = 0;
    boolean result = false;

    for(int i=0;i<pass.length();i++){
        if(((int)pass.charAt(i) >= 32 && (int)pass.charAt(i) <=47) || ((int)pass.charAt(i) >= 58 && (int)pass.charAt(i) <= 64)){
            count++;
        }
    }if(count >= numofSymbols){
        result = true;
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}
public boolean validnumofDigit(String pass){
    int count = 0;
    boolean result = false;
    for(int i=0;i<pass.length();i++){
        if(((int)pass.charAt(i) >= 48 && (int)pass.charAt(i) <=57)){
            count++;
        }
    }if(count >= numofDigit){
        result = true;
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}
public boolean validCapitals(String pass){
    int count = 0;
    boolean result = false;
    for(int i=0;i<pass.length();i++){
        if(((int)pass.charAt(i) >= 65 && (int)pass.charAt(i) <=90)){
            count++;
        }
    }if(count >= numofCap){
        result = true;
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}
public boolean validnumofLow(String pass){
    int count = 0;
    boolean result = false;
    for(int i=0;i<pass.length();i++){
        if(((int)pass.charAt(i) >= 97 && (int)pass.charAt(i) <=122)){
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count >= numofLow){
        result = true;
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}
public void setPassword( ){
    String newPassword ;
    boolean assume = true;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(assume){
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid password : ");
        newPassword = s.nextLine();
        if(!validLength(newPassword) || !validSymbols(newPassword) || !validCapitals(newPassword) || !validnumofLow(newPassword)|| !validnumofDigit(newPassword) ){
            if(!validLength(newPassword)){
                System.out.println("Password does not contain atleast 8 letters");
            }if(!validSymbols(newPassword)){
                System.out.println("Password does not contain atleast " + numofSymbols + " symbols");
            }if(!validCapitals(newPassword)){
                System.out.println("Password does not contain atleast " + numofCap + " Capitals");
            }if(!validnumofLow(newPassword)){
                System.out.println("Password does not contain atleast " + numofLow + " Lower Cases");
            }if(!validnumofDigit(newPassword)){
                System.out.println("Password does not contain atleast " + numofDigit + " numofDigit");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.print("Password Accepted : ");
            defaultPassword = newPassword;
            assume = false;
        }
        s.close();
    }
}
public String getPassword(){
    return defaultPassword;
}
}
public class Password2 extends Password1{

//Data field to represent minimum length of a passord based on the required settings. 
    
private int minSettings;

/** 2pts 
 * Default constructor that calls the superclass constructor with default 
 * settings (default settings at least 1 capitals, lowers,numofDigit,....
 * initialize the minSettings using the method actualLength
 */

    Password2(){   
    super(); 
    
   // call the superclass default constructor 
    minSettings=actualLength(); 
   // set minSettings to the actual min length of a password based on the settings

    }
/** 10pts
    Overloaded constructor 
    Make sure to prevent users from supplying settings that are
    invalid settings ( for instance , negative values or 0) or
    extreme cases like requiring more than 3 of (capitals,numofLow,
    symbols,numofDigit) in case, an extreme case supplied, 
    print a message that the settings supplied is not acceptable and 
    apply the default setting.
 */
    ArrayList<String> result; 
    public Password2 (int numofSymbols, int numofCap, int numofLow, int numofDigit )throws Exception{
        if(numofSymbols<2||numofCap<2||numofLow<2||numofDigit<2){
        throw new Exception("Settings supplied not accpeted");
    }
    this.numofSymbols=numofSymbols;
    this.numofCap=numofCap;
    this.numofLow=numofLow;
    this.numofDigit=numofDigit; 
    System.out.println("New Settings:"+"\n"+"Symbols: "+numofSymbols+"\n"+"Capitals: "+numofCap+"\n"+"Lowercase: "+numofLow+"\n"+"Digits: "+numofDigit); 
    }
        



/** 5pts 
 *   Create a method that checks the actual minimum length based on the 
 *   required settings
 *   Use ternary operator 
 *   if the addition of settings numbers is less than 8 , then minimum is 8
 *   for instance ( 1 capital, 1 small , 1 symbol, 1 number) = 4 which is less
 *   than the default length required, so minimum in this case 8
 *   if the addition of settings numbers is higher than 8 , then minimum is the
 *   addition of numbers. 
 *   @return the actual minimum length of the password
 */

public int actualLength() {
        int passMin=numofCap+numofLow+numofDigit+numofSymbols;
    return(passMin>8)?passMin:8;
    }

/** 10pts 
 * There are four methods that are similar to each other in Password1
 * one way to improve in here is to create one method that does their actions
 * take the first method that checks how many symbols and name it to checkRange
 * the method should look like this: 
 * public boolean checkRange( String pass,int required, char start,char end)
 * the method will take the range of char to be checked against the required
 * number of the specific type of numofSymbols. 
 * This method  will replace the 4 methods in Password1
 * This will reduce the lines of codes significantly.
 * 
 * @param pass
 * @param required
 * @param start
 * @param end
 * @return boolean
 */

public boolean checkRange(String pass,int required,char start,char end){
    int count=0;
    boolean result2=false;
    for(int i=0;i<pass.length();i++){
        if(pass.charAt(i)>=start &&pass.charAt(i)<=end){
            count++;
        }if(count>=required){
            result2=true;
            return result2;  
            }
    }return result2;
} 
public int getValues(){
    return numofSymbols;
}   

/** 10pts
 * Override the setPassword method
 * Use the annotation 'override'
 * Print out 4 suggested password based on the settings initialized by the constructor
 * Promote the user to choose from the suggested generated passwords or supply a 
 * password that would meet the requirements
 * Prevent consecutive numofSymbols (Use the consecutive method, should be created afterward)
 * use the checkRange method to check the ranges of capital, small, numofDigit, symbols
 * the reset of the method is the same as superclass setPassword
 */
    @Override
public void setPassword(){  // Declare a String to hold a password
    ArrayList<String> pw2= new Password2().Generate();
    System.out.println("Suggested Passwords:"+pw2);
    
    String Password=defaultPassword;

    // Decalre a scanner object to recive a password from the keyboard

        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

    // Declare a boolean variable to be set whenever a password meets the settings.
    
    boolean flag= true;
    
    // Loop until the user provides a correct password 
        
    while(flag){
            // Promt the user to enter the password based on the settings

            System.out.print("Enter Password based on set settings");
     
        
    // scan the next line and store in the String holding the password
        
        Password=scan.next();
    
    /* If the password provided is not the actual length required ,
       then print out a message and continue */

        if(Password.length()<actualLength()){
            System.out.println("Password length does not meet setting requrienments");
            continue;
        }
    
     /* If the password provided does not have the numofCap letters required ,
        then print out a message and continue
        pass to checkRange the range [65 -90] or[ A -Z]  */
    
            if(!checkRange(Password, numofCap,'A','Z')){
            System.out.println("Not enough numofCap letters");
            continue;
        }
     
    /* If the password provided does not have the numofLow letters required ,
        then print out a message and continue
        pass to checkRange the range [97 -122] or [a - z]  */
            
        if(!checkRange(Password, numofLow,'a','z')){
            System.out.println("Not enough numofLow letters");
            continue;
        }
  
    
     /* If the password provided does not have the symbols required ,
        then print out a message and continue
        pass to checkRange the range [32 -47] or [ space - /]  
       ( no need for this range [58-64])*/
    
        if(!checkRange(Password, numofSymbols,' ','/')){
            System.out.println("Not enough symbols included");
            continue;
        }
     
     /* If the password provided does not have the numofDigit required ,
        then print out a message and continue
        pass to checkRange the range   [48 -57] or [0 -9]  */
        
            if(!checkRange(Password, numofDigit,'0','9')){
            System.out.println("Not enough numofDigit included");
            continue;
        }
     
     /* If the password provided have consecutive charcters,
        then print out a message and continue
        pass to consecutive the password*/
            
        if(Consecutive(Password)==true){
            System.out.println("Consecutive numofSymbols are not allowed");
            continue;
        }

    /* Password provided meets all the settings
        set the global variable password to the new qualified password  
        set the flag to false, to stop iterations
    */
            flag=false;
        System.out.println("Password Accepted:");
        defaultPassword=Password;
        
    // end of while loop

        }
   
}    
    
 
/**10pts 
 * Create a new method that suggests few passwords based on 
 * the settings required , you have to use Random class to generate 
 * random values of ( numbers, numofSymbols, symbols , numofDigit) 
 * 
 * The method should generate based on the data fields settings
 * once generated a password, check if there is no consecutive values 
 * Store the generated password into an arrayList  
 * 
 * @return  ArrayList encapsulating 4 generated passwords
 */
    
    public ArrayList<String> Generate(){
        ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
        Random rand=new Random();
    int count=0;
    while(count<5) {
        String placeholder="";
        int a;
                     // Generate random A-Z
            
        for(int i=0;i<=numofCap;i++){
            a='Z'+1-'A';
            a=rand.nextInt(a)+'A';
            placeholder+=(char)a;
        }
                    // Generate from a-z
    
            for(int i=0;i<=numofLow;i++){
            a='z'+1-'a';
            a=rand.nextInt(a)+'a';
            placeholder+=(char)a;
        }
                    // Generate numbers 0-9
       
        for(int i=0;i<=numofDigit;i++){
            a='9'+1-'0';
            a=rand.nextInt(a)+'0';
            placeholder+=(char)a;
        }
                    // Generate symbols , 1st part 32-48
    
        for(int i=0;i<=numofSymbols;i++){
            a=48+1-32;
            a=rand.nextInt(a)+32;
            placeholder+=(char)a;
        }        
               // If no consecutive , add it to the ArrayList 
        
        if(Consecutive(placeholder)==true){
            continue;
        }
        count++;
        result.add(placeholder);
    }
 // return the ArrayList
        //System.out.println(result); 
        return result;
    }



public boolean Consecutive(String pass){
        boolean consecutive=false;
    for(int i=1;i<pass.length();i++){
        if(pass.charAt(i)==pass.charAt(i-1)){   
            consecutive=true;
        }   
    }  return consecutive;
}
/**public ArrayList getGenerate(){
*   Password2 gen=new Generate();
*   System.out.println("SuggestedPasswords: "+Generate());
*   }
*/
    public static void main(String[] args){
    

try{
    Password2 p1= new Password2();
    System.out.print("Default Password:");
    System.out.println(p1.getPassword());
    p1.setPassword();
    System.out.println(p1.getPassword());
  }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}


try{
    Password2 p2= new Password2(2,2,2,2);
    p2.setPassword();
    System.out.println(p2.getPassword());
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}

try{
    Password2 p3= new Password2(3,3,3,3);
    p3.setPassword();
    System.out.println(p3.getPassword());
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}

/*2pts  
Declare an instance of password to have these settings 
(0 capitals, 10 symbols, -1 numofDigit,100 small letters)
this settings is an extreme and thus the user 
should get a warning message and the default settings applied.
*/
    try{
    Password2 p4= new Password2(10, 0,-1,100);
    p4.setPassword();
    System.out.println(p4.getPassword());
    }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
}
```

}

Comment: OK... on second view, you say "the variables are not saved when [you] use this method" and then you include a bunch of code where you don't appear to be setting fields at all -- you only set a value for `placeholder`, but you don't seem to do anything with it. You have to set a value for the field to hold a value.

Comment: When you are drowning in confusion, the solution is to forget the grand scheme and **simplify**. In plain English, what is is you're trying to do? No offense, but at the moment, I'm seeing a lot of spaghetti. It would help your cause to get the basics working and then fancify your code with validations and so on later.

Comment: Thank you. I will try my best. It is a weird project and he wants very specific requirements

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `generate()` method isn't actually supposed to set the password -- it's only supposed to suggest four passwords to the user. When you say "the variables are not saved" did you mean that the password object is not saved, or is this arraylist of four suggested passwords is empty? Please be precise, or we're gonna be here all night guessing.

Comment: that top block of code is supposed to set the variables to what I have them set as correct? if you go to  the bottom of what I have pasted I have three blocks that overload Password2() with different values ie: Password2(1,1,1,1)

Comment: How can I access the variables that I saved using that overloaded method outside of that method. in the generate() method I still use those numofSymbol etc. variables. I want to know how to use the variables I stored with Password2(1,1,1,1);